# Native Mobile app approve payment and future payments in one go

Tags: paypal

I'm in the process of integrating PayPal into my mobile application, using PayPal's Mobile SDK v2.0.

Is it possible to have the end-user approve an immediate payment and pre-approve possible future payments together?

Here's the flow I am thinking about:

1. User logs in.
2. User wishes to make a payment using PayPal and checks a box for the application to not ask the user to re-enter PayPal credentials for future purchases.
3. User is taken to the PayPal native view and enters credentials.
4. User confirms the payment (and pre-approval of future payments) on the same view.
5. User comes back some time in the future and attempts to pay using PayPal again.
6. The application does *not* show the user the PayPal native view any-more.

Answer (score 1):

Sure this is possible. Basically the idea with future payments is to have your app securely store a token and refresh token once a user has given their consent. So if a user has given consent in the past, when they come to the payment screen you would already have the tokens stored and not need them to log in. When they click pay you would simply use the refresh token to get a new token on your back end server and use the new token to pay without any user interaction.

If you don't have previously stored tokens for the user who wants to pay, you would then show them the PayPal view to log in and give consent, get the authorization code and then use that to get the token and refresh token. You then use the token you just got to pay immediately and store the two tokens for later use.